# MIPS code acting funny - simple case regarding print statements

Tags: mips

I am having real problems trying debug my code to malfunctioning print statements. I am using MARS MIPS simulator. The following code prints:

degree!
test
degree!
test

When it should print

degree!
test

```
.data

test:       .ascii      "degree!\n"

test4:      .ascii      "test\n"

.text
main:
la  $a0, test
li  $v0, 4
syscall 

la  $a0, test4
li  $v0, 4
syscall 

j EXIT


EXIT:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strings are not null-terminated. Use `.asciiz` instead of `.ascii`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.asciiz` instead of `.ascii` to get NULL terminated strings.